# how to change a table cell border color by assigning css class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, border, tablecell

I would like to change the border colour of a table cell by changing the CSS class of the table cell.

I have tried to change the "border" attribute, it does not work.
I have tried to change the 4 border attribute individually, it does not work also.

```js
function go() {
  $("#target11").addClass("selectCellBorderTop");
  $("#target11").addClass("selectCellBorderLeft");
  $("#target11").addClass("selectCellBorderRight");
  $("#target11").addClass("selectCellBorderBottom");
}
```

```css
input[type="text"][value="1"] {
  background-color: #ff99cc;
}

input[type="text"][value="2"] {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}

input[type="text"][value="3"] {
  background-color: #ccffcc;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  //border:1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  margin: 0px;
  border-top: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-right: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.selectCellBorderLeft {
  border-left: 3px solid black!important;
}

.selectCellBorderRight {
  border-right: 3px solid black!important;
}

.selectCellBorderTop {
  border-top: 3px solid black!important;
}

.selectCellBorderBottom {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="target00">
      <input type="text" value="1">
    </td>
    <td id="target01">
      <input type="text" value="2">
    </td>
    <td id="target02">
      <input type="text" value="3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="target10">
      <input type="text" value="1">
    </td>
    <td id="target11">
      <input type="text" value="2">
    </td>
    <td id="target12">
      <input type="text" value="3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="3">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
```

When I click  on the go button, all the central cell borders colour should be overridden; unfortunately, not all borders colour are overridden.

Comment: It is due to `border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: Why the top and left border are not overridden only? Why the other border can be overridden only?

Comment: check the duplicate to understand the rules, they are defined

Comment: According to the specified post, the wider border overrides the narrow border, but both the original border width and new border width are the same. So, I don't why some borders colour can be overridden, some borders does not.

Comment: you could eventually use a workaround with outline : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rgogRp

Comment: from the duplicate : *if ... come from same type of element, such as two rows... then color is taken from borders that are the topmost and the leftmost.*